# How to avoid the login_sucess.html?

Tags: windows-phone-7, facebook-c#-sdk

How can one avoid to have to show this redirect_uri = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html" each time you login with your WP7 app.

I have a share button in my app which should post content to the facebook page of the user that logged in. Currently when a user already has entered username/password they still get to see the white screen "login_success.html" first and then the item gets posted and it returns back to the app page.

How can you avoid this screen in the app flow ?

I am using the facebook sdk C# v6...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your browser control invisible after you got the access tokens

Comment: private void webBrowser1_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed; ........ }   // This still gives me a white screen...